# what's ref in react native and when should i use ref?

Tags: forms, react-native, ref

I'm working on react native project, i created forms with react native components.
I used TextInput to edit a state value like this :

```js
<TextInput
    shake
    keyboardAppearance='light'
    autoFocus={false}
    autoCapitalize='none'
    autoCorrect={false}
    keyboardType='default'
    returnKeyType='next'
    value={this.state.sector}
    onChangeText={sector => this.setState({ sector })}
/>
```

With console.log the sector value i get correctly the current value after input change, but i have seen some examples with ref like this :

```js
<TextInput
    shake
    keyboardAppearance='light'
    autoFocus={false}
    autoCapitalize='none'
    autoCorrect={false}
    keyboardType='default'
    returnKeyType='next'
    value={this.state.sector}
    ref={input => (this.sectorInput = input)}
    onChangeText={sector => this.setState({ sector })}
/>
```

i don't understand this operation :

```
ref={input => (this.sectorInput = input)}
```

can someone explain what's the ref and why we used with an input and when should i use a ref ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access TextInput [methods](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#methods) then you have to create reference of that component, then using reference you can use it's method.

For example you have form in your app and you want that when user fill the first field and after that you want to set focus on next field then you can do like this :

```js
<TextInput
    shake
    keyboardAppearance='light'
    autoFocus={false}
    autoCapitalize='none'
    autoCorrect={false}
    keyboardType='default'
    returnKeyType='next'
    value={this.state.sector}
    ref={input => { this.sectorInput = input}}
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
        this.nextField.focus();
    }}
    onChangeText={sector => this.setState({ sector })}
/>

<TextInput
    shake
    keyboardAppearance='light'
    autoFocus={false}
    autoCapitalize='none'
    autoCorrect={false}
    keyboardType='default'
    returnKeyType='next'
    value={this.state.sector}
    ref={input => { this.nextField = input}}
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
        this.handleSubmit();
    }}
    onChangeText={nextField => this.setState({ nextField })}
/>
```

Now, when user will fill the `sector` field then if he press next, then `nextField` will automatically get focused.